# Get WPF ContextMenu opening direction in ControlTemplate triggers

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to style `ContextMenu` based on its opening direction. If it's opened upwards, I'll style it one way, if not - the other way.

Unfortunatelly, `Placement` property of `ContextMenu` doesn't help. It's always equal to `MousePoint`. I'm talking specifically about `ContextMenu` class, not MenuItem (where Placement of popup element would help).

Please, help me to get real opening direction of a `ContextMenu`.